# ionic 2 error when start new project

Tags: ionic2-select

E:\SocialLoginDemo>ionic start HelloWorld12 blank --v2
Creating Ionic app in folder E:\SocialLoginDemo\HelloWorld12 based on blank project

Installing npm packages...

```
Error with start undefined
Error Initializing app: There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
There was an error with the spawned command: npminstall
Caught exception:
 undefined
```

Mind letting us know? https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-cli/issues
my version information
Your system information:

> You have been opted out of telemetry. To change this, run: cordova
>   telemetry on.
>   6.3.1

```
Ionic CLI Version:2.1.0 
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.0-beta.1 
OS: Node Version:v4.6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

There was some problem in spawned command "npminstall" but now they have fixed this issue. Mostly it should work now and if not kindly share screenshot of errors being thrown.